# Simplest way of concatenating Strings and variables

Tags: java

In Java, when logging multiple variables with some meaningful information I tend to end up with something like:

```
logger.debug("Comparing A["+i+"] = "+A[i]+", with B["+j+"] = "+B[j]+" --> "+A[i]==B[j]);
```

I wonder if there is a simpler and cleaner way to do so, let's say something like:

```
logger.debug("Comparing A[@i] = @A[i], with B[@j] = @B[j] --> @(A[i]==B[j]));
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `String.format`?

Comment: What is the type of `logger`? I'd have assumed `java.util.logging.Logger` but that has no `debug` method.

Comment: No, here is an instance of `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`.

Comment: @sergi123 In my personal experience, there is one completely different option to "optimize" such debug logs: **don't use them**. Long time back, some guy told me: "you only need trace statements when you don't have good unit tests". After many months of practice, I have to agree. If my unit tests cover the inner logic of my classes; then I have 100% trust that "minimal in/out" tracing is good enough. Meaning: I trace incoming arguments; and return values. (And even that; I am mainly doing that so I can prove to users of my code that my class does what it expected to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `log4j`, you can also use `{}` as a placeholder:

```
logger.debug("Comparing A[{}] = {}, with B[{}] = {} --> {}", 
  i, A[i], j, B[j], A[i]==B[j]);
```

You can see it [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/messages.html).

Comment: Note this is available only since log4j 2. The older log4j 1.2 does not support this. Logback does, and so does slf4j (which you probably should use anyway).

Comment: Version 2 [supports it](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/messages.html) though.

Comment: Not what I had in mind, but looks like the simplest. I hate all those %d, %b, ...

Answer (score 3):

There's `String.format`, but it requires you to move the expressions out-of-line:

```
logger.debug(String.format("Comparing A[%d] = %d, with B[%d] = %d --> %b", i, A[i], j, B[j], A[i] == B[j]));
```

Other than that, no, there isn't.

Comment: In which version of JDK can you find this method?

Comment: @reporter Since Java 5.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you use Logback, it provides methods with the following signature (similar on all log levels)

```
debug(String format, Object[] args)
```

which can be used as

```
logger.debug("Hello. I am a {}", msg);
```

Comment: ...and what does the method do?

Comment: The docs: http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance. Using slf4j enables this no matter which logging backend you use.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [java.text.MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class.
this class has the Format method that can help you to assign parameters to {Number} placeholders...

for example:

`logger.debug(MessageFormat.Format("hello {0} {1}", "john","smith"));`